Arbitrary NS_ERROR_NET_RESET and "000" HTTP status code when reverse-proxying with nginx with HTTP3 / QUIC enabled
I have nginx/1.27.0 (latest mainline version for today) acting as reverse-proxy to expose grafana instance, running in docker, to Internet.
I enabled HTTP3 / QUIC on nginx side and noticed that some (arbitrary and rare) requests to Grafana are stuck (Grafana sometimes shows “N/A” in some panels). Most of HTTP3 requests are processed without problems.
HTTP3 / QUIC is generally working (verified by https://http3check.net/):

In nginx error log there is nothing. In nginx access log those stuck requests have "000" status code with "0" bytes transferred:
1.2.3.4 - - [12/Aug/2024:06:24:05 +0000] "POST /api/ds/query?ds_type=prometheus&requestId=Q137 HTTP/3.0" 000 0 "https://grafana.example.com/d/123456789/linux-server-overview?orgId=1&refresh=30s&var-DS_PROMETHEUS=***&var-job=***&var-node=***&var-diskdevices=***&from=now-1h&to=now" "my-user-agent-here"

In Firefox Developer Tools those stuck requests are red, don't have any HTTP status code, have "0" size and NS_ERROR_NET_RESET in "Transferred" column.
If disable HTTP3 / QUIC in nginx, with HTTP1+HTTP2 only - all works fine.
How to debug this?
nginx config (based on documentation):
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream grafana {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000; # docker port
}

server {
    server_name grafana.example.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/grafana.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/grafana.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://grafana;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /api/live/ {
        # proxy Grafana Live WebSocket connections
        proxy_pass         http://grafana;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400,h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'; # for HTTP3/QUIC
    http2 on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 quic;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/grafana.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/grafana.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = grafana.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name grafana.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

